# How to query by reference in Firestore (using the Cloud Console)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if someone knows if there is a way to query by reference using the Firestore console (with the Panel View or with the new Query Builder).

I've been trying to do this all day but can't figure it out if its even possible to do it on the UI.

What I mean is the following scenario:

- Having two collections A and B, with B having a `reference` property to an A document.
- Knowing the Document ID from A in advance.
- Query B to know all documents that has, as a reference, that A document.

This is totally possible on code, my problem is doing it on the UI for a quick check every now and then.

Comment: Good question. I can't get it working [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMUpe.png) either, so I'm asking around. Would love to hear it  if somebody else gets it working already of course. :)

Comment: Thats exacly whats happening to me!, I try a lot of combination with no results :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't any way to query for a document reference field in the Firestore console. It's a valid request though, so I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) with the team.

Comment: I filled a feature request and now its in discussion. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Frank!, I filled the request some months ago, and I know there is no specific date to fix this problem, but do you know if the request is at least talked inside the firebase team?